# Fetch HealtKit data from 3rd party devices

Tags: ios, healthkit

Can my app fetch HealtKit data from third party devices? For example from Garmin? In `HKSource` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksource), it seems that user would have to use Garmin app to transfer HealtKit data from his/hers device to iOS device and only then my app could use that data:

> devices need a companion app to collect and save the data to
>   HealthKit.

Or can I write app, that would handle fetching data from 3rd party devices?

**tl;dr** Can my app get HealthKit data from 3rd party devices

Comment: with own device u can easily do,see https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-healthkit-part-1--cms-24477

Comment: @VikasRajput Will the data from HealthKit include data from 3rd party devices? Lets say from Garmin fitness device?

Answer (score 0):

Third party developers can provide import functionality to health app via the normal Health Kit API on iOS.

Some apps scrape or use web API such as [Sync Solver](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sync-solver-for-fitbit/id935306292?mt=8) exist to get FitBit data from the cloud to the local health app on iOS. Some such as [Health Importer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/health-importer/id930943780?ls=1&mt=8) are more general. (proper disclosure: I work on this app)

We have an app on the store that is designed specifically for importing arbitrary CSV data into HealthKit / Health.App.
i hope without API you can't do this.

Comment: I am little bit new to HealthKit, so if user has a fitness device, can my app get HealthKit data from that device? Or will user have to use fitness device app to import data to HealthKit and then my app will be able to get that data?